# How to display different infoBox on button clock

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on an application in `sinydashboard` in which the user generates a random number on the click of a button. The random number corresponds to a row in a dataframe which I need to display on the dashboard using an `infoBox`. Each `infoBox` needs to persist on the screen until the user closes the application.

I tried generating a new output variable on each click in `server.R`, however I could not find a way of referencing it in `ui.R`. Minimal example below. I've not included generating a name for an output variable on each button click as that's not working at all.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = ""),

                    dashboardSidebar(),

                    dashboardBody(fluidRow(
                      box(
                        width = 3,
                        actionButton(inputId = "generateButton",
                                     label = "Generate")
                      ),

                      box(infoBoxOutput("rnum1"))
                    )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  randomData <- data.frame("RN" = runif(100, 1, 100))

  observeEvent(input$generateButton, {
    randomNumber <- floor(runif(1, 1, 100))
    dataRow <- randomData[randomNumber,]

    # Display dataRow in a persistent infoBox
    # in a way that 5 clicks will produce 5 boxes
    # Number of clicks is not known in advance
    output$rnum1 <- renderInfoBox({
      infoBox("Number", dataRow)
    })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You're asking for an `infoBox` but you dont even have one in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want, at leat this a draft. You'll need a reactive variable to store the already generated numbers to be able to have something persistent.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = ""),

                    dashboardSidebar(),

                    dashboardBody(actionButton(inputId = "generateButton",
                                               label = "Generate")
                                  ,
                                  uiOutput('infoBoxes'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  randomData <- data.frame("RN" = runif(100, 1, 100))

  rv <- reactiveValues()


  observeEvent(input$generateButton, {
    randomNumber <- floor(runif(1, 1, 100))
    dataRow <- randomData[randomNumber,]
    print(dataRow)

    rv$persistent <- c(rv$persistent, dataRow)

    # Display dataRow in a persistent infoBox
  })

  output$infoBoxes = renderUI({
    if(length(rv$persistent) > 0 ) {
      fluidRow(
        Map(function(x) infoBox('title', rv$persistent[x]), 1:length(rv$persistent))
      ) 
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```